# Given a free module with a well-defined finite rank, are all of its linearly independent sets finite?

Tags: modules, free-modules

Given a free left $R$-module $M$ over a ring $R$ with Invariant Basis Number, does every linearly independent subset $L \subseteq M$ have cardinality at most $n$?

Over integral domains like $R=\mathbb Z$, the answer is yes, by an adaptation of Gaussian elimination. But I don't know if it's true in general.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thank you. Which of his books?

Comment: As a partial answer, it is true that every linearly independent set in a rank $n$ free module over a commutative ring has cardinality at most $n$ by adapting https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136/atiyah-macdonald-exercise-2-11. One of the answers includes a reference to Lam's "Lectures on Rings and Modules".

Comment: OK, so I've just learnt that this is called the "strong rank condition" property of a ring. So it may indeed fail.

Comment: @EthanMartin Thanks. That's very helpful.